# jQuery .prop stop execution without error

Tags: javascript, jquery, execution

I am working on a simple thing to uncheck all radio buttons in a sec when a page is loaded. For a bit, I've been tearing my hair out about this:

```
alert('uncheck');
$("input[name=PreviousMailAID]:checked").prop('checked', false);
alert('uncheck2');
```

What happens is I get the first alert, then the radio button is unchecked, but I do not get the next alert.

Does anyone know why .prop causes execution to fail **without error**?

EDIT: It's jQuery 1.3.2 that I'm using with this, in Chrome.

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: What browser is it failing in?

Comment: It seems to be working but I´d prefer `$('input[name="PreviousMailAID"]').prop('checked', false);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Works fine. [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4WnGy/)

PS: `.prop()` comes from jQuery 1.6, before that you have to use `.attr()` method.

Comment: You are correct. I will see if I can update my jQuery. I thought of that when I looked at your answer. jQuery 1.3.2 can produce this error.

Comment: @BenDauphinee `.prop()` comes from jQuery 1.6, before that you have to use `.attr()` method.

Comment: This should have been a comment.

Answer (score 1):

[`jQuery().prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) was added at [version 1.6](http://api.jquery.com/category/version/1.6/). Upgrade your jQuery version, or use:

```
$("input[name=PreviousMailAID]:checked").attr('checked', false);
```

Alternatively, you can combine jQuery with vanilla JavaScript:

```
$("input[name=PreviousMailAID]:checked").each(function(){this.checked = false;});
```

Answer (score 0):

For jquery 1.3.2 use this

```
alert('uncheck'); 
$("input[name=PreviousMailAID]:checked").attr('checked', false); 
alert('uncheck2');
```